# Braintree drop in UI generate new nonce

Tags: braintree

I've integrated the braintree drop in UI in my project and have added paypal, google pay and visa payments. Everything works fine, payments are submitting to the API etc. But if I use submit a payment which fails using the values from - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#transaction-amounts. The nonce has then been used, amending my basket price and submitting again fails as the nonce has already been used. I've looked through the documentation and all I can find about nonces is that it can only be used once (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-method-nonces) and nothing around refreshing or requesting a new nonce. Ideally I'd like to avoid having to force the user to enter the payment details again.

Is there another way of automatically requesting a new nonce?

Comment: what version client-SDK are you using?

Comment: @hollabaq Android, sorry forgot to mention it. Between yesterday and now I've changed my flow so the dropin ui is launched on pressing the Pay button. A solution could be useful for somebody else looking for a solution though if there is one.

Comment: Having the exact same issue :-/

Comment: Having this issue with braintree android sdk version 3.4.0 (released 3 days ago)